# 日本語版ではバッジの獲得条件を緩和するべきでは？

Tags: 機能の要求, バッジ

例えば、「人気の質問」バッジの獲得条件は Question with 1,000 views となっており、
英語版でも同じ条件です。英語版は世界中の人が使うのに対して、日本語版は主に日本人
しか使わないので、同じ獲得条件でもその難易度はかなり異なるのではないかと思います。

日本語版では獲得条件の数値を変えるべきではないかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 同じようにローカライズされた[Stack Overflow ポルトガル語版](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)では、本家英語版と同じ条件のままのようですね。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

オープンベータから半年で60名近く獲得され、[この3ヶ月に投稿された質問](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/318211)でも既に6件が1000PVを超えているのを見ると、個人的にはこのままでもいいかなと思っています。

今後もユーザー数は増えていくと期待したいですしね。
（バッジの獲得条件が厳しいからこのサイトを使わない、なんて人はいないはず・・・）

なお、**権限**については[コミュニティ主導での運営を早く機能させるため](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172976)という理由があるため、日本語版SOをはじめとするベータ版サイトでは条件が緩和されています。

Comment: 数字を出していただきありがとうございます。
他の銅バッジの獲得数も見てみて、
それらに比べてそう無茶苦茶は難しくないんだ、ということで納得しました。